# GRPC how to reuse client connection?

Tags: node.js, grpc

```
 // ServiceA - proto
const proto = grpc.load({
    root: protoDir,
    file: 'serviceA.proto'
});

 // ServiceB - proto
const proto = grpc.load({
    root: protoDir,
    file: 'serviceB.proto'
});


let clientA = new ddl_proto.com.mypackage.serviceA(common_url, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
clientA.functionOne({
    options: JSON.stringify(user_options)
}, (error, response) => {
    console.log(response)
})



let clientB = new ddl_proto.com.mypackage.serviceB(common_url, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
clientB.functionTwo({
    options: JSON.stringify(user_options)
}, (error, response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

If `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` are served by same server, is there any way by which i can reuse the client object ?

Can i do something like this :

```
let commonClient = new grpc.Client(common_url, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

commonClient.ServiceA.functionOne();

commonClient.ServiceB.functionTwo();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer from grpc developers](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/359)

Currently, you cannot explicitly attach a single connection to clients for two different services. However, if you create two clients with the same URL, credentials, and options (if any), they should end up using the same underlying connection.

Thanks to [Michael Lumish](https://github.com/murgatroid99)